# Catch events by dynamically adding Handler using Code Generation

Tags: vb.net, events, trace, il, dynamicmethod

I need to hook up all events in an application and trace all information (raising, arguments, etc.).

I found this at Stackoverflow: 
[Tracing all events in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802774/tracing-all-events-in-vb-net)

However, I need a solution that not only writes the called event to console, but calls TraceVerbose with parameters showing sender and eventargs.

I am still working on getting to know dynamic code generation and IL, so I don't have a clue about how to get the code to call a trace method with parameters from the event.

Can anyone tell me how to do this (in VB.NET)?

Comment: You want to look at [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). Works with VB.net too. There is a community edition that will get you up and running and examples for exactly what you want are on the site too.