# page/control lifecycle

Tags: c#, asp.net, lifecycle

I have usercontrol x in a page, within usercontol x is usercontrol z. I need to do something to usercontrol z after an event fires in usercontrol x. I understand this is very generic, but it just lays out a simple premise for my issue.

Is there a simple way to get a list of all events that fire in the page lifecycle whether I am subscribed to them or not to find out what events fire between Event A on the page and Event B on control z? I would think that there would be something like this when page tracing is turned on, but I don't see any events listed. I imagine that it would be something that the pipeline could generate, maybe I could use reflection to get a list?

I found this topic hard to search against in general, maybe I am using bad keywords...
I did find an old project on codeproject.com, but I was hoping that there would be something more elegant available by now.

*To clarify, I'm looking to generate a list after a postback of every potential event (subscribed or not), in firing order from init to unload, of all controls on a page.

THIS POST: [Tracing all events in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802774/tracing-all-events-in-vb-net)
gets me a little bit closer, however these are lists on a per control basis, not in chronological order.

Answer (score 1):

Enable trace with <%@ Page Trace="true" %> in page attribute. that should display life cycle events in sequence.

Comment: This gives a page level list (about 20 events), Again, I am looking for the actual list subscribed/non-subscribed events for all controls for 1 complete roundtrip postback.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're just looking to see what the events are in general, and in what order they fire, [check out this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). As far as getting them...well, that depends on what you mean. It could be as simple as getting them through reflection:

```
EventInfo[] events = this.GetType().GetEvents();
```

Comment: I dropped this in the page's prerender, and It's showing me 15 events for the page, this is where I'm going with this, I may be able to get recursive with it and get the list I'm looking for...

Comment: After looking at it, I'm not sure I can get the events in chronological order, do you have a suggestion for that?

Comment: Not exactly, but if you know the events ahead of time and in what order they will fire (which you do), you can define that programmatically and then access it at runtime as needed.

Answer (score 0):

The [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) on MSDN lists all of the events fired by a `Page` from `PreInit` to `Unload`. Most of these events fire on any class that inherits from `System.Web.UI.Control` as well.

---

**Update**

Now that I understand your intention better, one possible solution would be to loop through the events of every control and assign an event handler that logs the calling of the event. There is at least one way to [retrieve all of the event handlers assigned to an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783267/how-to-get-a-delegate-object-from-an-eventinfo/3783491#3783491), and it shouldn't be too difficult to adapt that code to assign an event handler instead.

Comment: I'm familiar with the ol' standard events. I think a lot of .net is event management, I'd think there would be a tool that would get you this list on demand...